# Monit - send alert if mailserver down

Tags: monit

Is there a way to make monit alert other than by mail:

Sometimes the mailservers are down. How would I get a message about it? 
My idea was to make monit pass an http request to a defined service, is this possible? (for example a gelf message to my graylog server or even a self-made service)

Comment: Don't use the email server you're monitoring as the email server for sending alerts.

Comment: You re right therefore I will use a fallback mail server. The Problem still remains: I won't get any info if the whole server is down... But i think, only mmonit can handle this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple ways:

Either you could use some different mail provider (its always a good idea, if notifying does not depend on your infrastructure) for sending out email or even relay them to a sms gateway or you could use monits ability to call scripts like

```
if <condidtion> then exec </path/to/script> as uid <uid> and gid <guid>
```

Your script can do whatever magic you want to have.